# Create AD user in a different domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I created a series of scripts for creating domain users. Since every domain where we create users requires different parameters and conditions, I have one script for each domain. But in case of one domain I have a problem. For this domain the manual procedure is like this:

1) open dsa.msc

2) connect to the "xyz" domain (the user is being created from a server in "abc" domain)

3) Create the user (operation for 10 to 15 minutes, that's why I created the scripts)

Unfortunately, when I run my script, I get the error message, that "The server is unwilling to process the request" (That's the precise complete error message) during execution of New-ADUser cmdlet. I suppose the reason is the need to perform the step 2 in the procedure I described above. So I somehow need to simulate it in the script, but I have no idea how to do that.

This is how the command is defined:

```
$params = @{
        'GivenName'             = $First_name_val.Text
        'Surname'               = $Second_name_val.Text
        'DisplayName'           = $Display_name
        'AccountPassword'       = $password
        'Path'                  = $Location_val.Text
        'Name'                  = $User_name_val.Text
        'CannotChangePassword'  = $Cannot_chg_pass.Checked
        'PasswordNeverExpires'  = $Pass_not_expires.Checked
        'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $Must_chg_pass.Checked
        'Enabled'               = !($Account_disabled_val.Checked)
        'Description'           = $GECOS_val.Text
        'Office'                = "NA"
        'OfficePhone'           = "NA"
        'Title'                 = $Job_Title_val.Text
        'Department'            = $Department_val.Text
        'Company'               = $Company_val.Text
        'SamAccountName'        = $User_name_val.Text
        'UserPrincipalName'     = $User_name_val.Text + "@woodplc.com"
        'EmailAddress'          = $Email_Address_val.Text
        'PassThru'              = $true
    }
    $New_user = New-ADUser @params
```

Definition of `$User_name_val.Text` is here:

```
#region Real name of the user
[void]$AD_user_creation.SuspendLayout()

$Display_name_lbl                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_lbl.text           = "User`'s real name"
$Display_name_lbl.AutoSize       = $true
$Display_name_lbl.width          = 25
$Display_name_lbl.height         = 10
$Display_name_lbl.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)

$First_name_val                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$First_name_val.Text             = "a."
$First_name_val.multiline        = $false
$First_name_val.width            = 120
$First_name_val.height           = 20
$First_name_val.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)

$Second_name_val                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Second_name_val.multiline       = $false
$Second_name_val.width           = 120
$Second_name_val.height          = 20
$Second_name_val.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,10)

$Display_name_val                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Display_name_val.Text           = ""
$Display_name_val.width          = 250
$Display_name_val.height         = 20
$Display_name_val.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)

$showFullName = { $Display_name_val.Text = ($First_name_val.Text + "." + $Second_name_val.Text) }

[void]$Second_name_val.Add_Leave( { & $showFullName } )
[void]$First_name_val.Add_Leave(  { & $showFullName } )
#endregion

#region User name of the user
$User_name_lbl                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$User_name_lbl.text              = "User logon name"
$User_name_lbl.AutoSize          = $true
$User_name_lbl.width             = 25
$User_name_lbl.height            = 10
$User_name_lbl.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)

$User_name_val                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User_name_val.multiline         = $false
$User_name_val.width             = 250
$User_name_val.height            = 20
$User_name_val.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,70)
$LogonName = {$User_name_val.Text = ($First_name_val.Text + "." + $Second_name_val.Text)}

[void]$Second_name_val.Add_Leave({& $LogonName})
[void]$First_name_val.Add_Leave({& $LogonName})
[void]$AD_user_creation.ResumeLayout()
#endregion
```

Comment: can you share how you are connecting to domain xyz to create a user with `New-ADUser`? Are you using the server parameter?

Comment: You should use both the `-Server` (a DC on "xyz" domain) and the `-Credential` parameters on the `New-ADUser` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

The error `"The server is unwilling to process the request"` means that some of your input values are invalid. For example, the OU you are providing could be invalid (maybe a space that shouldn't be there), or the `SamAccountName` might be too long or contain an invalid character, etc.

If you show the full command you are using I might be able to spot something.

If there was an issue connecting to the server or authenticating, then the error message would be different.

Comment: I'll try to write the command to the question, but it won't be easy, I hope it will be understandable.

Comment: It really depends on the actual values. For example, is `$Location_val.Text` actually a valid OU? Is `$User_name_val.Text` actually a valid `SamAccountName`? etc.

Comment: Yes, they are all valid values, in other domains everything works fine, the location is selected using a custom made browser which never gave invalid value. SamAccountName is just a string of characters; on other domains there was never a problem with creating an account. On all domains we tried the same names.

Comment: `SamAccountName` does have restrictions on how long it can be and what characters can be in it, which are listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname). I'm not saying that is necessarily the problem, since I can't see your values. But it could be.

Comment: You can try removing one value at a time and trying after each one and see if it either works or the error message changes.